# understand Bayesian probability fastest

Tags: bayesian

I am looking for a good book to learn at least joint probability Bayes rules. I have a bit of experience with probabilities. I have got a course last semester in stochastic process. Could anyone be able to refer to me a good book for understand Bayesian probability fastest?

Thanks!

Comment: A question about best intro Bayesian book is here: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/125/what-is-the-best-introductory-bayesian-statistics-textbook

Comment: Yes, but I dont even know if the book cover 'joint probability Bayes rules'

Comment: Yes, all those books cover multi-parameter Bayesian models.